# z-index or :hover sometimes work, sometimes not

Tags: jquery, css, hover, z-index

I am really scared about what happens. I am building a little site with some animation, CSS 3D transform with a bit of jQuery.

The code it's a bit too long to put it on here, so I create **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7dTS/embedded/result/)**.

Anyway, the structure is very simple at all (this is just full code, with non vendor-prefixs, for `article`):

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <h1>2012</h1>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>2013</h1>
  </article>
</section>
```

```css
.article {
  position: absolute;
  width: 370px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: grey;
  z-index: 50;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 3px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-reflect: below -10px -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 0%, transparent 40%, transparent 100%);
  transition: margin-top 0.3s, width 0.3s, height 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s, top 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transform: perspective(900px) rotateY(25deg) translateZ(-90px);
}

section article:hover {
  margin-top: -30px;
  width: 430px;
  height: 310px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.8s;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0);
}
```

The problem is, when I access to the page, the `:hover` sometimes work and sometimes not. It **seems that sometimes some other element is over the article** —which couldn't really be possible seeing that there are no more elements. There is really no need to add `z-index` (there's a class `.activo` which just comes up after clicking an article), and without it happens the same. Sometimes work, sometimes not…

Please try on the [link to example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7dTS/embedded/result/) and reload it a few times. This happens in Safari, Chrome and Firefox —seems to work a bit better in FF.

Just found out, that **when** I reload the page and while loading **I get fast to the elements with the mouse** —hover articles— then **it works** as expected. If I wait until it's loaded to get hover, it doesn't work.

In addition, there's a bit of jQuery to manage the following articles to the hovered one goes more to the right. I have to do it with JavaScript because they must find the place back after hover a brother element, and can't even use `margin-right` to the hovered one because they are absolute positioned elements —and they should be absolute because after click them, they cover the whole body.

```js
$('article').hover(function (event) {
    $(this).nextAll('article').each(function () {
        izquierda = izquierda_original[$(this).attr('id')].izquierda + 360;
        $(this).css('left', izquierda + 'px');
    });
}, function (event) {
    $(this).nextAll('article').each(function () {
        izquierda = izquierda_original[$(this).attr('id')].izquierda;
        $(this).css('left', izquierda + 'px');
    });
});
```

`izquierda_original[]` is just an object containing the `left` original value of each element.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I figure out finally that the problem is the `body` element. When the height of it arise the articles, I can't hover them. This is even more weird. It's like that `body` is hover they child elements.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with Chrome (in fact it worked thrice and then not anymore despite many refreshs). Ok with Firefox. First thought: `transform` has also an effect with `z-index`, for example this sort of problem: http://daneden.me/2012/04/css-transforms-and-z-index/

Comment: Thanks for the link @FelipeAls, will have a read on it, it could be possible that the problem is caused by transform because it seems to be very weird. Anyway, please see my edit.

Comment: Removing `body { height: 100px; }` fixes it for me in Chrome, although I have no idea why at the moment. This will break the background for you though. I can also confirm that it does work sometimes as well. Lastly, removing the CSS `transform` also fixed it for me, so it might be something to do with the perspective shift.

Comment: You are right: setting body height to 0px instead of 100% seems to solve the problems. Cann't understand why, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason the body tag is overlaying your elements.

Here is what fixed it for me.

First add a `z-index` to the body tag like so:

```
body{
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
}
```

Then add a higher `z-index` to the section:

```
section{  
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}
```

This will retain your background and keep the element functional.

Comment: Thank you @bukka. The relative positioning of the section wasn't needed, because the z-index wasn't even needed to work. Anyway, after clicking `article` it will cover the whole page, so `section` couldn't have any position different than `static`.